# Audio keeps playing after closing the browser on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I made a mobile website that (amongst other stuff) plays an audio. When I close the browser on my phone (only occurs on Android, not iOS) the audio just keeps playing. How do I prevent that?

I've tried to pause the audio on the `onunload` event but without success.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds as if another app is used for playing the audio (i.e. not the browser). Check the filetype of the audio, and be careful to offer at least mp3 and ogg formats inside the `<audio>` tag in order to be compatible to all browsers, so that *they* will play the audio, and not open it with another app. (And make sure to define the `type` attributes correctly)

Comment: I used a mp3 file´and the sound comes from the browser, if I swipe down on the homescreen to open the notifications or whatever, I have an audio controller for the playing audio which has the symbol of the corresponding browser

Comment: Edit: Only occurs on Android, not iOS

Comment: Well, I would add an ogg file as a second option inside the `audio` tag